# How to make cy.visit() wait for ajax requests to complete?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I would like to use `Cypress.Commands.overwrite()` to make the `cy.visit()` method do what it normally does and then wait until a loader element is no longer in the DOM, indicating that AJAX requests have completed. My goal is exactly this instead of creating a new command. The reason is to avoid situations where, e.g., someone might unknowingly use the unmodified `cy.visit()` and then assert that some elements not exist, when they possibly could exist and just not have loaded yet.

While overwriting the default command, I appear to be running into problems with Cypress' use of promises. From the manual, it is clear how to overwrite `cy.visit()` when one wants to do stuff before calling the original function. However, I am unable to find an example, where the original function is called first and custom stuff happens only after that.

So what I would like to do with the `overwrite()` command is this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('visitAndWait', (url) => {
  cy.visit(url);
  cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('not.exist');
});
```

I have tested and can confirm that the above does what I need it to. Here are some attempts to make this work as an overwrite, all of which fail:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  return originalFn(url, options).then(() => cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('not.exist'));
});

Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', async (originalFn, url, options) => {
  const res = await originalFn(url, options);
  await cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('not.exist');
  return res;
});
```

Both fail with this:

[image: Error message for first two snippets.]

> Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  originalFn(url, options);
  return cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('not.exist');
});
```

And the last one fails with this:

[image: Error message for the last snippet.]

Is this kind of an overwrite possible at all in Cypress, and if so, how is it done? Thank you!

**EDIT:**

The test code which causes the error in the last case is here:

```
cy.visit('/');
cy.get('[data-cy="switch-to-staff"]').click();
```

Basically it tests a user role mocking panel by clicking a button that should mock a staff role.

Comment: The first two attempts using `.then()` and `await` are wrong because Cypress commands are not promises, they are enqueued test steps. The third attempt is basically correct, but the error you show obviously has nothing to do with the test steps in the overwrite, since it refers to `cy.click()`. Please show the complete test usage of the overwritten command.

Comment: @MarionMorrison updated with the code you requested. As you can see, I'm just calling the overwritten `cy.visit()` and then `cy.click()`. The button is visible at all stages and the test passes if I don't overwrite `cy.visit()`.

Comment: How does your latest edit relate to the problem?

Comment: ...asking in order to get some clarity.

Comment: As the question stands, the error cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned by @richard-matsen, you should check that your loader exists before waiting for it to disapear. That may be why you get the `detached from DOM` error with your `switch-to-staff` element.

Something like this might work for you:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  originalFn(url, options);
  cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('be.visible');
  cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('not.be.visible');
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion changing `.should('exist')` to `.should('be.visible')`, as `cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]')` already does the "exists" check.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **cy.wait()** to wait for the page to completely load then check for the loader to not exist

```
it('Visit the app', function () {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('not.exist');
  })
```

Wait Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html

Comment: I'm looking to specifically overwrite `cy.visit()`, this does not answer the question. Also, using `cy.wait()` is generally discouraged, especially here since there is a clear way to see when the queries have resolved, the absence of the element tagged with `data-cy="loader"`. Waiting a set amount of time on every visit would make the test tremendously longer.

Comment: Rather than `cy.wait(3000)` you could first wait for the loader to appear `cy.get('[data-cy="loader"]').should('exist');`, then wait for it to disappear. In any case, you have the right idea - the loader will not necessarily be present immediately after the visit command.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the first error by using `.then()` like that:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url) => {
    originalFn(url).then(() => {
        // cy...
    });
});
```

For waiting on requests I'm using two approaches.

First Approach: Like the other answer suggests watch the loading icon.

Second Approach: Intercept the actual request like that:

```
cy.intercept({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '**random/part/of/the/ajax/request/url**',
    }).as("request");

// Here should be the line that triggers the ajax request
// for example: originalFn(url)...
// or cy.click();

cy.wait("@request", { timeout: 10_000 });
```

Comment: The problem is, which intercept returns last? Unless you stub everything, the internet random response time is going to make it flaky.

Comment: if you've got many different request and need to wait for every request yes, this will lead to a race condition. If you are waiting for one part of the page to be rendered you can be more specific and intercept just the one request you need to be finished. In my use-cases there is one specific request that ALLWAYS takes long. But there is no loading animation.